# parsing html and selecting first table with second span

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Hi I am parsing the html page with htmlagilitypack My app has been working well before, but recently had problems due to html page changes.

The problem is I'm parsing a specific table (first table), but it looks like it's going to another table after parsing it and giving an ArgumentOutOfRangeException error

This is html content

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="a1">
<a href="/subtitles/joker-2019/farsi_persian/2110062">
<span class="l r positive-icon">
Farsi/Persian
</span>
<span>
Joker.2019.WEBRip.XviD.MP3-SHITBOX
</span>
</a>
</td>
<td class="a3">
</td>
<td class="a40">
&nbsp;
</td>
<td class="a5">
<a href="/u/695804">
meisam_t72
</a>
</td>
<td class="a6">
<div>
►► زیرنویس از میثم ططری - ویرایش شده ◄◄ - meisam_t72 کانال تلگرام&nbsp; </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td class="a1">
<a href="/subtitles/joker-2019/farsi_persian/2087508">
<span class="l r bad-icon">
Farsi/Persian
</span>
<span>
Joker.2019.1080p.HC.HDRip.1400MB.DD2.0.x264-GalaxyRG
</span>
</a>
</td>
<td class="a3">
</td>
<td class="a40">
&nbsp;
</td>
<td class="a5">
<a href="/u/546114">
filmb.in
</a>
</td>
<td class="a6">
<div>
filmbin.Cloud | با نسخه HC-HDRip هماهنگ شد&nbsp; </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And that's how page parsing

```
HtmlDocument doc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync(url);
HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]//tbody");
if (table != null)
                {
                    foreach ((HtmlNode cell, int index) in table.SelectNodes(".//tr/td").WithIndex())
                    {
                       // i get error in this line
                       string Name = cell.SelectNodes("//span[2]")[index].InnerText;
                    }
                }
```

The point is that first all the items in the first table are parsed well and when I enter the second table (which should not be) I get an error.

Comment: Whats the purpose of [index] in your code there? Is it to pull the first or second span item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things I noticed that could be causing the issue in your code.

1. In your foreach loop, you are using `//` to search for span[2]. You should know that `//` will cause the search to look at your entire code, not just cell. So, it would select Name x number of times the loop executes (which is 5 in this case).
2. Use of index doesnt quite seem to be valid here. There is always x number of spans but you are basing the index on index of tr which doesnt quite make sense. that is what throws the exception

   > Out of Range Exception.
3. Seems like you are aware, but want to iterate it again. `//` will search the entire document. `.//` will iterate under the tag you are on, if within a loop.
4. Following code will produce the output you are looking for within //table/tbody. Anything under //table/tr will be ignored because tr is "not" under tbody. Second table in your example will be ignored.

```
    HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table//tbody");
    if (table != null)
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode cell in table.SelectNodes(".//tr/td"))
        {
            var nodeWithSpanTag = cell.SelectSingleNode(".//span[2]");
            if (nodeWithSpanTag != null)
                Console.WriteLine(nodeWithSpanTag.InnerText.Trim());
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
    Joker.2019.WEBRip.XviD.MP3-SHITBOX
```

if i use `//span` (instead of `.//span`), i get the above line printed 5 times.

This example will produce the same result as above,

```
 Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table//tbody//tr/td//span[2]")?.InnerText.Trim());
```